# Display user specific data in html form with oop php

Tags: php, oop

I wanted to show a form specific to user with his personal detailes, and then allow him to update that information. But in order to do that first i need to show his detailes in the form so he can update them.

I have a function ShowUserInformation() in class MyClass:

```
function ShowUserInformation()
{
    $query = "SELECT id, name, email FROM saloni WHERE id = '$_SESSION[ID_korisnika]'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)):
        $id= $row['id'];
        $name= $row['name'];
        $email = $row['email'];
    endwhile;   

    return $result;
}
```

My question is: How can i display value of $name, or $email, or $id on another page in text box?

If i do it in procedural way it works when i do this:

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $name ?>" name="name" class="" />
```

But, how can i display the $name,$email,$ID... in oop way?And there won't be just these 3 variables, there will be much more so i need something that can apply to that.
i've included file, created object...

```
$my_class = new MyClass; //create an object of class
```

HTML - i've tried something like this...

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $my_class->ShowUserInformation($name)?>" name="name" class="" />
```

I'm new in PHP and oop so be easy with me :)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You **ShowUserInformation()** function must be return a **$name**. In you code a function return **$result**

And HTML must be looks like that:

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $my_class->ShowUserInformation() ?> name="name" class="" />
```

Comment: Thank for the answer, but i will have a lot more text fields, so i can not retur just a single value. I need it to return value somehow so i can just change in HTMl $name, or $email, $phone because i will have a lot more rows in query, i just showed three to shorthen tho code i post.

Answer (score 0):

Fast and dirty way:

```
class YourClass {

    /**
     * Ident
     */
    public $id;

    /**
     * Name
     */
    public $name;

    /**
     * Mail
     */
    public $email;

    public function showUserInformation($name) {

        //[...]        

        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)):
            $this->id= $row['id'];
            $this->name= $row['name'];
            $this->email = $row['email'];
        endwhile; 

        //[...] 

    }
}


<input type="text" value="<?php echo $my_class->name?>" name="name" class="" />
```

Comment: Thank for the answer, but how can i call it without declaring them as class variables, because there is a lot of rows, i've just put three to shorthen the code.